# split window vertically instead of horizontally in sql-mode

Tags: emacs

When I connect to the database, it opens a new window by split horizontally, but that will cause the buffer too narrow to display the sql and hard to read. So how to disable split the windows horizontally? I want to split the windows always vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming sql-mode uses emacs to dertermine the best way to spilt (and not forces a certain way) and you now have the buffers next to each other and want them atop of each other you can do this by

```
(setq split-height-threshold 0)
(setq split-width-threshold nil)
```

If the directions are wrong due to a horizontal vertical misunderstanding you can switch `nil` and `0`